# PostgreSQL: prompt inside a function error

Tags: sql, database, function, postgresql

I'm trying to use a \prompt inside a function but I have the following error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "\"
LINE 5:       \prompt "...
```

Here is the function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION typeAccount(type VARCHAR(50)) RETURNS VOID AS
$$
  BEGIN 
    IF type = 'direct' THEN
      \prompt "Please type the id -> " variable
      SELECT choose_account(:variable);
    END IF;
  END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. `\prompt` is a plsql CLI command not a SQL statement. You can't use it in the body of a function.